# Error connecting red5 from Flash Media Live Encoder

Tags: java, red5, fmle

Since a couple of days I'm trying to get the red5 authdemo to work (in Eclipse Juno).

see: http://blog.infrared5.com/2012/05/red5-authentication/
demo-project source: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7316897/ir5/blog/red5-auth.zip

The red5 Server seems to work fine:

```
...
[INFO] [Launcher:/authdemo] org.red5.demo.auth.Application - Available auth providers: 1
```

But I've got the following error/exception when I try to connect **rtmp://localhost/authdemo** via Flash Media Live Encoder 2.3:

```
[INFO] [NioProcessor-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.codec.RTMPProtocolDecoder - Action connect
[INFO] [NioProcessor-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Connecting to: [WebScope@66bfa709 Depth = 1, Path = '/default', Name = 'authdemo']
[INFO] [NioProcessor-2] org.red5.demo.auth.Application - W3C x-category:session x-event:connect c-ip:127.0.0.1 c-client-id:0    
[INFO] [NioProcessor-2] org.red5.demo.auth.FMSAuthenticationHandler - appConnect
[INFO] [NioProcessor-2] org.red5.demo.auth.FMSAuthenticationHandler - Connection: RTMPMinaConnection from 127.0.0.1 : 53362 to 127.0.0.1 (in: 3259 out 3073 )
[ERROR] [NioProcessor-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler - Error connecting {}
        java.lang.ClassCastException: org.red5.server.net.rtmp.status.StatusObject cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection.connect(RTMPConnection.java:284) ~[red5.jar:na]
        at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaConnection.connect(RTMPMinaConnection.java:87) ~[red5.jar:na]
        at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPHandler.onInvoke(RTMPHandler.java:268) ~[red5.jar:na]
```

( ... lots of similar error-messages ... )

```
[WARN] [Red5_Scheduler_Worker-2] org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Closing RTMPMinaConnection from 127.0.0.1 : 53362 to 127.0.0.1 (in: 3259 out 3177 ), with id 1 due to long handshake
```

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Any ideas that might solve my problem?

Thanks in advance!